# MdInput inside a MdRadioButton does not update the value in the form

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to nest an `MdInclude` inside an `MdRadioButton`, that is, if I select a specific button/value an additional input field (associated with that particular button) is enabled, for example

```
Shipping

O - Same Address
X - Different Address ...........
```

Which to me is a pretty common case.

The way I tried to go about it is as follows:

```
<form role="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <md-radio-group formControlName="shipping" (change)="shippingChange($event)">
    <md-radio-button value="same">Current Address</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button value="different">
      <span>Different Address:</span>
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="Address" formControlName="address">
      </md-input-container>
    </md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
  <button md-raised-button type="submit">OK</button>
  <h4>Shipping: {{shipping}}</h4>
  <h4>Address: {{address}}</h4>
</form>
```

and here's the associated script:

```
public ngOnInit() {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      shipping: 'same',
      address: { value: '', disabled: true }
   });
}

public shippingChange($event) {
   if ($event.value === 'different') {
      this.form.get('address').enable();
   } else {
      this.form.get('address').disable();
   }
}

public submit() {
   if (this.form.valid) {
     this.shipping = this.form.value.shipping;
     this.address = this.form.value.address;
   }
}
```

(here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQta6rVW9xJlaGPitzSo?p=preview), to toy around with). The form appears to be working, but on submit the value for `address` is not included (presuming I chose 'Different Address'). On inspection of `this.form.controls` I noticed that `disabled` is still set to `true`, which is probably why the value is not present.

However, I explicitly enabled that control in the event handler above, so what am I missing here?

Comment: If I got your question well, you're trying to get a value of a control even if it it's disabled. Is it right? If so, use `form.getRawValue()` instead of `form.value`.

Comment: Not really, the control is enabled, it's just that the form still thinks it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem here is that, as soon as I enter text in `MdInput` and hit "Submit" that same control fires `change()` events of its own which bubble up to `MdRadioGroup`.

The event handler then looks at `value`, which is `undefined` and disables the `MdInput` again, which is why the form ignores its value.